# knockoutjs data-bind ="tap:controller.method.bind()" is not firing in mobile/ipad

Tags: html, ipad, knockout.js

I have HTML page,different controllers and viewmodels. In html file, I have a button and tap event as shown below.

```
<a href="#" data-bind="visible: gameIsReady(),tap: controller.handleStartButtonClick.bind(controller),event:{ mousedown: $root.controller.buttonActivate.bind($root.controller),mouseup: $root.controller.buttonDeactivate.bind($root.controller)}"></a>
```

Based on the template, the event hits the particular controller and a method in it. It works as expected in desktop. But does not hit the method in mobile/ipad.

I am new to knockout Js. Can anyone tell me what is wrong here ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `event` binding like you do for `mousedown` and `mouseup`

```
<a href="#" data-bind="visible: gameIsReady(), event:{ mousedown: $root.controller.buttonActivate.bind($root.controller), mouseup: $root.controller.buttonDeactivate.bind($root.controller), touchend: $root.controller.handleStartButtonClick.bind($root.controller) }"></a>
```